# ruby `encode': "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

Hannibal episodes in tvdb have weird characters in them.

For example:

```
Œuf
```

So ruby spits out:

```
./manifesto.rb:19:in `encode': "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
    from ./manifesto.rb:19:in `to_json'
    from ./manifesto.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

Line 19 is:

```
puts @tree.to_json
```

Is there a way to deal with these non utf characters? I'd rather not replace them, but convert them? Or ignore them? I don't know, any help appreciated.

Weird part is that script works fine via cron. Manually running it creates error.

Comment: set proper codepage like `ISO-8859-1` instead of `ASCII-8BIT` to the variable `@tree` as `@tree.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')`. Because `ASCII-8BIT` is used just for binary files.

Comment: I guess the `cron` environment is somehow resolving the default input encoding for you. I *think* your input is actually UTF-8 in the first place (C3 is a common byte to see at the start of a multi-byte character from European characters)

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ: In this case I think the input may not be an ISO-8859 variant, but UTF-8 that has been incorrectly defaulted. Although with just one sample point without the matching character it *could* be anything

Comment: @NeilSlater why do you think? isn't the char `Œ` in the iso cp?

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ: On balance of probabilities I think UTF-8. The C3 byte value will turn up a lot in UTF-8 encoded text. We only have one error message, so it's just a best guess on limited data.

Comment: @salivan if the source is from/for rails please provide the request. or any additional code and data.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ it is not from rails, I'm reading system files with Dir.glob and filenames are created by sickbeard.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ it is not cron, but root account that resolves problem. Running sudo ... and it gives no error. ;S

Comment: if sudo solves the problem, the problem was in default cp, please do knowledge which default cp is, and set it in ruby for default user. like this: `Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8` replacing utf to proper one

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ sorry. what is default cp?

Comment: run `irb` then issue `Encoding.default_external`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ you were right! root and normal user produce different results. User: #<Encoding:US-ASCII>, root #<Encoding:UTF-8>. But how do i set it permanently utf-8? Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8 works only while I'm inside irb.

Comment: This will be a locale setting. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Encoding.html#documentation - and look at the section headed "External encoding". You can also set the encoding directly on your IO object in the source code, which is often more flexible and re-usable than a global setting.

Comment: I have the following env variables set up:
`LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8` set them in .bashrc properly similar to `export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8` etc. but not exactly `ru_RU`, but as in root account.

Comment: to view env just run in bash: `env|grep UTF-8` form root

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems you should use another encoding for the object. You should set the proper codepage to the variable `@tree`, for instance, using [iso-8859-1](/questions/tagged/iso-8859-1) instead of [ascii-8bit](/questions/tagged/ascii-8bit) by using `@tree.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')`. Because `ASCII-8BIT` is used just for binary files.

To find the current external encoding for ruby, issue:

```
Encoding.default_external
```

If [sudo](/questions/tagged/sudo) solves the problem, the problem was in default codepage (encoding), so to resolve it you have to set the proper default codepage (encoding), by either:

1. In ruby to change encoding to [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8) or another proper one, do as follows:

   ```
   Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
   ```
2. In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), `grep` current valid set up:

   ```
   $ sudo env|grep UTF-8
   LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
   LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
   ```

   Then set them in `.bashrc` properly, in a similar way, but not exactly with `ru_RU` language, such as the following:

   ```
   export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
   export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
   ```

Answer (score 23):

File.open(yml_file, 'w') should be change to File.open(yml_file, 'w**b**')

Comment: The posted code in the question does not contain a line `File.open(...)`. So what do you mean?

Comment: Okay, so this answer actually helped me. If you write YAML to a file like this: `File.open('/path/to/file.yml', 'wb') { |f| YAML.dump(data, f) }`, you will get the error in the title if you leave out the `b`.

Comment: the question say nothing about the file open

Comment: Actually it helped me because I was having this error `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8` when doing `file.puts data` with `file = File.open("response.txt", "w")` but after adding the `b` param it worked fine. But it would come in handy if the explanation was included here @unplugandplay

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problems when saving to the database. I'll offer one thing that I use (perhaps, this will help someone).

> if you know that sometimes your text has strange characters, then
>   before saving you can encode your text in some other format, and then
>   decode the text again after it is returned from the database.

example:

```
string = "Œuf"
```

before save we encode string

```
text_to_save = CGI.escape(string)
```

(character "Œ" encoded in "%C5%92" and other characters remained the same)

=> "%C5%92uf"

load from database and decode

```
CGI.unescape("%C5%92uf")
```

=> "Œuf"

Answer (score 2):

I just suffered through a number of hours trying to fix a similar problem. I'd checked my locales, database encoding, everything I could think of and was still getting ASCII-8BIT encoded data from the database.

Well, it turns out that if you store text in a binary field, it will automatically be returned as ASCII-8BIT encoded text, which makes sense, however this can (obviously) cause problems in your application.

It can be fixed by changing the column encoding back to `:text` in your migrations.