# JSON.parse throwing Encoding::UndefinedConversionError

Tags: ruby, encoding

Getting the following error on windows:

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xEF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

### Code:

```
text = File.open(file, 'r:binary', &:read); #opens file and reads it with r:binary flag
puts text; #works i get here, outputs the below file contents
data = JSON.parse(text.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)); #fails here with above error
```

***Note:*** I've tried R:UTF-8 as well.

---

### File Contents:

```
{
  "Environments": [
    {
      "Environment": "UT",
      "Configuration_Directory": "configs/",
      "Files": [
        {
          "Source": "Web.ENV.config",
          "Destination": "Web.config"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Environment": "UAT",
      "Configuration_Directory": "configs/",
      "Files": [
        {
          "Source": "Web.ENV.config",
          "Destination": "Web.config"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Environment": "Staging",
      "Configuration_Directory": "configs/",
      "Files": [
        {
          "Source": "Web.ENV.config",
          "Destination": "Web.config"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Environment": "Production",
      "Configuration_Directory": "configs/",
      "Files": [
        {
          "Source": "Web.ENV.config",
          "Destination": "Web.config"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I had this problem and this help resolve it 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309669/ruby-encode-xc3-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8-encodingundefinedconversionerr

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this problem where the original string was UTF-8 with BOM but Ruby had encoded it as ASCII-8bit. I convert the string to a byte array and then back into a string while forcing the encoding to be UTF-8.

```
string_value.bytes.pack("c*").force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

Comment: Eric you saved me a lot of Googling <3