# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 with yaml file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, yaml

I cant write yml file with ruby on rails 4.2...

```
file_path = Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', I18n.locale.to_s, "#{I18n.locale.to_s}.dialogs.yml")
data      = YAML.load_file file_path
File.open(file_path, 'w:utf-8') { |f| YAML.dump(data, f) }
```

I just open existing yaml file and write same content, but this error occur

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

I save with utf8 encoding the yaml file, but nothing change...

What solution?

EDIT

`Encoding.default_external` is already define to UTF-8

I tried to force encode by recurion of hash, but nothing change.

I have define in config app `config.encoding = "utf-8"`

So all what i can test is in UTF8... I don't understand why this error occur.

When error occur, my .yml file is empty...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby \`encode': "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309669/ruby-encode-xc3-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8-encodingundefinedconversionerr)

Comment: This post don't give the good solution for my case...

Comment: related: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-list/50219 might be a bug

Comment: Don't know why, but this works: `File.open(file_path, 'w') { |f| f << data } `

Comment: YAML requires the text be in UTF-8 (or UTF-16 if a BOM is present). You'd need to read the file as text (encoding would probably be ISO-8859-15 or similar, not ASCII-8BIT), convert it's encoding to UTF-8 and _then_ parse it as YAML.