# Ruby 2 and Rails 4 encoding issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding, character-encoding, ruby-2.2

I'm working on a project that is migrating from a rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.x to ruby 2.2.x and rails 4.2.4 version.

When the project goes to production server, it started to throw encoding errors like this:

`"\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`

followed by an stacktrace like:

```
["/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:34:in `encode'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:34:in `to_json'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:34:in `to_json_with_active_support_encoder'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:57:in `to_json'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:223:in `generate'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:223:in `generate'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:101:in `stringify'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:35:in `encode'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:22:in `encode'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:37:in `to_json_with_active_support_encoder'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.2/lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:19:in `dump'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.2/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:25:in `dump'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.2/lib/multi_json.rb:136:in `dump'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/resque-1.24.1/lib/resque/helpers.rb:25:in `encode'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/resque-1.24.1/lib/resque.rb:173:in `push'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/resque-1.24.1/lib/resque/job.rb:51:in `create'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/resque-1.24.1/lib/resque.rb:271:in `enqueue_to'"
 "/var/www/suba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/resque-1.24.1/lib/resque.rb:252:in `enqueue'"
 "/var/www/suba/app/controllers/call_center/chat_controller.rb:6:in `transcript'"
```

and the `chat_controller.rb` line 6 on `transcript` method:

```
  def transcript
    Resque.enqueue(Chat::SessionTranscript, read_request_body)
    head :ok
  end

  def read_request_body
    xml = request.body.read
    Rails.logger.info("XML: #{xml}")
    xml
  end
```

In another point of our code base we solved this issue using a code like:

```
string.encode("UTF-8", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")
```

but the same error starts to appear in other parts.

Have anyone passed for this and how are you dealing with?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: does this SO Q and A cover your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309669/ruby-encode-xc3-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8-encodingundefinedconversionerr

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by replacing like 34 at

(...)/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb

for:

```
self.force_encoding('utf-8').to_json_without_active_support_encoder(options)
```