# How can I fix Ruby on Rails special characters typed into a form. (ò, ā)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am getting this error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8): 
                           <td><p><%= row.notes.to_s.encode('UTF-8', {:invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '?'}).gsub("\n", "<br>").html_safe %></p></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       <% end %> 
                     </tbody> 
                   </table> 
                 </div> 
                 <div id="eventDetailModal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="eventDetail" aria-
```

I have this at the top of my RequestController file in the first line.

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

I have this in my ScheduleCalls.erb file first two lines.

```
<% # encoding: utf-8 %>
<% content_for :head do -%>
```

File was created in Sublime so it isn't the editor.

This is in my application.rb file

```
# Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

UPDATE:

Not sure if it matters but I am using MongoDB and the fields are be saved as Strings.

In another file on the admin view I am seeing this error.

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8)
```

Comment: No. Its a form field and people type in their names or anything they want in the description field. The form lets them type what they want, but it is erroring out once they save it because of special characters they typing in.

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23382078/1202324